# Why is the set $\{u\in C^1(\overline{\Omega}): \|\nabla u\|_\infty<1, u=0\text{ on } \partial\Omega\}$ open?

Tags: real-analysis

$\Omega$ is a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^N$ with boundary $\partial\Omega$ of class $C^2$ and $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ is the usual sup-norm in $L^\infty(\overline{\Omega})$. Why is the set $\{u\in C^1(\overline{\Omega}): \|\nabla u\|_\infty<1, u=0\text{ on } \partial\Omega\}$ open?

Comment: I think that it should be use the fact that the definition of a continuous function is one for which preimages of open sets are open. But how?

Comment: I don't think its open in $C^1(\overline{\Omega})$. adding a small constant to $u$ to get $u+\epsilon $ takes you out of the set due to the boundary condition, and $\|u-(u+\epsilon)\|_{C^1} = \epsilon $ can be made arbitrarily small

Comment: Similar to [Check that D={y∈C1[x0,x1]:y(x0)=0=y(x1)}
is open](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2836649/check-that-d-y-in-mathcalc1x-0-x-1yx-0-0-yx-1-is-open).

Comment: Not in $C^1(\overline{\Omega})$. The question is why it is open in $C_0^1(\overline{\Omega}):=\{u\in C^1(\overline{\Omega}):u=0 \text{ on } \partial\Omega\}$ as Calvin Khor said?

Comment: Well in this case $F: C^1_0 \to \mathbb R, \ F(u):=\|\nabla u\|_\infty$ is Lipschitz with constant 1,
$$ |F(u)-F(v)| \leq \|u-v\|_{C^1}$$
and your set is the pre-image of $(-\infty,1)$

Comment: Open in what? $\,$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question as clarified in comments is to check that it is open in $C^1_0(\overline{\Omega})$. Define $F: C^1_0 \to \mathbb R, \ F(u):=\|\nabla u\|_\infty$. Note that this function is Lipschitz with constant 1, since
$$ |F(u) - F(v)| = | \|\nabla u \|_\infty - \|\nabla v\|_\infty| \leq \|\nabla(u-v)\|_\infty \leq \|u-v\|_{C^1}$$
and your set can be written as $F^{-1}((-\infty,1))$.